# Is there an easy way to do computations with NetCDF4 files in Python?

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I downloaded several NetCDF4 (not _CLASSIC) from repositories on the internet. These files are monthly averages, and from 12 of these files, I want to compose a global average map. I have tried several packages and approaches, but I am getting nowhere. Does anyone have a solution? Part of the start of my code is attached and two files are uploaded.

Months to include: 12

Years to include: 5

Files to include: 60 (5 x 12)

Eventually, I want to do the computations with Python since this is way faster than ArcGIS. I might opt for visualisation of (hopefully) one NetCDF4 file in ArcGIS.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

filenames = glob.glob('/Volumes/USB/ArcGIS/Projects/Carbon_responses/GLDAS_025_20122016/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A2012??.021.nc4')

ds_list = []
for fn in filenames:
    ds = nc.Dataset(fn)
    ds_list.append(ds)
```

Two sample files (one year, one month):

- [GLDAS_NOAH25_M.A201203.021.nc4](https://data.gesdisc.earthdata.nasa.gov/data/GLDAS/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.2.1/2012/GLDAS_NOAH25_M.A201203.021.nc4)
- [GLDAS_NOAH25_M.A201204.021.nc4](https://data.gesdisc.earthdata.nasa.gov/data/GLDAS/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.2.1/2012/GLDAS_NOAH25_M.A201204.021.nc4)

What could be useful approaches (e.g. extracting variables as NumPy arrays, performing computations, and creating a new NetCDF4 file) or useful packages?

Comment: You could try xarray or my package nctoolkit https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Both will let you do what you are trying to do